# How to preprocess aerial image for coastline detection

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, python

I am working on a program that gets exact pixel values of the shoreline in a given image. What is the best way to preprocess these types of images in order to make my life easier?

A sample image:

[image]

Comment: Preprocess to do what?

Comment: Preprocess in order to make it easier for a program to get exact pixel values of where the shoreline is. (Make the water black and the sand white or something along those lines.)

Comment: Will the image be similar every time or will weather change resulting in different lighting and shadows, waves, washed up seaweed, people sunbathing etc.  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you want to be able to segment the land from the water this way defining a path for the shoreline.

For this task I recommend you using an edge detection algorithm. A simple **vertical Sobel filter** should be enough given the image that you have provided. More details about its insides and API call [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html).

Do you have images with different meteorological conditions? Your algorithm should be robust when it comes to different lighting scenarios: night, rain etc (if that is the case).

A thresholding with respect to the tones that you have in your image might also help, details [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).

For a proper binarized image the following [contour finding methods](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) proposed by OpenCV should do the job for you.